# How do i get authorization code in the followling examples?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have tried to implement example in the following link .But I am getting confusion that how i will get authorization code ?
i have studied this link
https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet

Answer (score 0):

imho, that is a bad place to start. That page implies that you can implement Oauth without understanding Oauth. Bad idea. Better read this page https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2 which explains how Google does Oauth, then this page https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ to see it in action. Until you understand what is going on, don't read anything else coz it will only confuse you.

Of course, others may have different opinions.